# Haystack and Solr- Fail To Clear Index

Tags: python, django

I wanted to implement a search feature for my web app. I choose Haystack and Solr. After following the procedure in the docs. I tried to rebuild solr index ( python manage.py rebuild_index ) but I'm getting the below error. What I'm I missing?

```
   WARNING: This will irreparably remove EVERYTHING from your search index in connection 'default'.
   Your choices after this are to restore from backups or rebuild via the `rebuild_index` command.
   Are you sure you wish to continue? [y/N] y

   Removing all documents from your index because you said so.
   Failed to clear Solr index: [Errno 10061] No connection could be made because the   target machine actively refused it
   All documents removed.
   Indexing 2 fincribs.
   Failed to add documents to Solr: [Errno 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it
```

Haystack settings

```
   HAYSTACK_CONNECTIONS = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'haystack.backends.solr_backend.SolrEngine',
        'URL': 'http://127.0.0.1:8983/solr'
        # ...or for multicore...
        # 'URL': 'http://127.0.0.1:8983/solr/mysite',
    },
 }
```

Models

```
     class Fincrib(models.Model):
           user=models.ForeignKey(User)
           title=models.CharField(max_length=250, unique=True)
           address=models.CharField(max_length=200)
           city=models.CharField(max_length=200)
           state=models.CharField(max_length=200)
           main_view=models.ImageField(upload_to="photos",blank=True, null=True)
           side_view=models.ImageField(upload_to="photos",blank=True, null=True)
           pub_date=models.DateTimeField()

           def __unicode__(self):
               return self.title
          def get_absolute_url(self):
              return self.title
```

Search_index.py

```
         class FincribIndex(indexes.SearchIndex, indexes.Indexable):
               text=indexes.CharField(document=True, use_template=True)
               address=indexes.CharField(model_attr='address')
               city=indexes.CharField(model_attr='city')
               state=indexes.CharField(model_attr='state')
               pub_date=indexes.DateTimeField(model_attr='pub_date')

               def get_model(self):
                   return Fincrib
               def index_queryset(self):
                   return self.get_model().objects.filter(pub_date__lte=datetime.datetime.now())
```

Comment: Is there solr running, and is there running at the given port?

Comment: I cd my django project like this: C:\Python27\Scripts\meek After that I input: python manage.py rebuild_index and I got the above error.

Comment: And do you have a solr server running on your machine?

Comment: I DON'T THINK SO. HOW WILL I GET IT RUNNING?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then first of all, try to get [solr running](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrTomcat#Tomcat_on_Windows).

Comment: Thanks. I'm trying to add the connector attribute in server.xml but I'm getting this error:  Please check if this file is opened in another program. Nothing is opened, don't know why I'm unable to save.

Comment: Before editing, try to stop Tomcat. There should be a GUI tool to manage Tomcat called tomcat7w.exe, or something like that.

Comment: I've successfully setup solr server and it's running! I can visit http://localhost:8080/solr/admin/ But I'm still getting the above error. What will I do?

Comment: It seems that you don't use the port 8983, but 8080. Change your HAYSTACK_CONNECTIONS settings.

Comment: I've changed it to 8080 still not working. I'm getting import error:  No MODULE NAMED BEAUTIFULSOUP.

Comment: Try to install BeautifulSoup with pip.

Comment: I guess I'm getting there.. I've installed beautiful soup. Let me check it out.

Comment: I'm getting this error: Failed to add documents to solr: [Reason: doc=meebapp.fincrib.1] Unknown field: 'city']

Comment: See the note for solr: http://django-haystack.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorial.html#reindex

Comment: After building and dropping the schema.xml file in C:\wamp\solr. I'm still getting the above error. What can I do? Thanks for your ongoing support!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12913/discussion-between-kosii-and-picomon)